# Jquery range slider is changing value of left slider when right slider is moved?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery slider that allows a user to select multiple times by selecting a time range. I parse the times using some shorthand math. For some reason when I push back the right slider from one side it adds onto the slider to the left. So I end up with a time selected that not was not selected. In other words, one slider is changing the value of the other slider.

I've tried changing

`var val0 = $(".slider-range-" + index).slider("values", 0),
                    val1 = $(".slider-range-" + index).slider("values", 1),`

to

`var val0 = $(".slider-range-" + index).slider("values", 0),
                    val1 = $(".slider-range-" + index).slider("values", 0),`

This seems to take away the value from my right slider though.

Every slider is added an ID using:

```
var clone = $("#timeRowDup").clone();
                clone.removeAttr("id");
                var cloneHtml = clone.html();
                cloneHtml = cloneHtml.replace(/###/g, interviewIndex);
```

And some remaining code:

```
function slideTime(event, ui) {

                var index = event.target.id.split("-").pop();

                var val0 = $(".slider-range-" + index).slider("values", 0),
                    val1 = $(".slider-range-" + index).slider("values", 1),
                    minutes0 = parseInt(val0 % 60, 10),
                    hours0 = parseInt(val0 / 60 % 24, 10),
                    minutes1 = parseInt(val1 % 60, 10),
                    hours1 = parseInt(val1 / 60 % 24, 10);
                startTime = getTime(hours0, minutes0);
                endTime = getTime(hours1, minutes1);
                setSliderTimes(index, startTime, endTime);
            }

 function getTime(hours, minutes) {
                var time = null;
                minutes = minutes + "";
                if (hours < 12) {
                    time = "AM";
                } else {
                    time = "PM";
                }
                if (hours == 0) {
                    hours = 12;
                }
                if (hours > 12) {
                    hours = hours - 12;
                }
                if (minutes.length == 1) {
                    minutes = "0" + minutes;
                }
                return hours + ":" + minutes + " " + time;
            }

$(".slider-range-" + interviewIndex).slider({
                    range: true,
                    min: 510,
                    max: 1020,
                    values: [startTimeVal, endTimeVal],
                    slide: slideTime
                });
```

HTML:

```
<div id="slider-###" style="min-width:200px;margin:10px 0px;" class="slider-range-###"></div>
```

Each slider should give the exact time selected without one slider effecting the time of the other.

Comment: Is there html for the sliders?

Comment: I added the HTML in relation